# Get both the top-n values and the names of columns they occur in, within each row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, top-n

I have a dataframe like in this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,1],'b':[4,6,0],'c':[0,4,8]})
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 | 6 | 4 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 8 |
+---+---+---+
```

for each row, I need (**both**) the 'n' (in this case two) highest values and the corresponding column in descending order:

```
row 1: 'b':4,'a':1
row 2: 'b':6,'c':4
row 3: 'c':8,'a':1
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are exactly three columns and their names are `a,b,c` or do you want a general answer?

Comment: I want a general answer, just used three columns for the sake of simplicity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting top N columns for each row in data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297319/selecting-top-n-columns-for-each-row-in-data-frame)

Comment: Actually it's a perfect duplicate of [Find top-n highest-value columns in each pandas dataframe row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955182/find-top-n-highest-value-columns-in-each-pandas-dataframe-row) with `nlargest = 2`. There's your answer. (I can't redirect my close vote now.)

Comment: @smci thanks, but I'm not sure if this is the same. I need the correspondence between the values. I need to know on wich column were the top values at the beginning.

Comment: I should have renamed it [Find names of top-n highest-value columns... in row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955182/find-names-of-top-n-highest-value-columns-in-each-pandas-dataframe-row)

Comment: Ok I see now you wrote "for each row, I need (EDIT: **both**) the top-n values and the corresponding column in decending order". Yeah sorry, that's slightly different.

Comment: By the way, your output rownames are the not-so-Pythonic 1,2,3 instead of 0,1,2

Comment: A near-duplicate, except with floats, and using column indices instead of names: [For each dataframe row, get both the top-n values and the column-indices where they occur](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518092/for-each-dataframe-row-get-both-the-top-n-values-and-the-column-indices-where-t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways, both adapt from [@unutbu's answer to "Find names of top-n highest-value columns in each pandas dataframe row"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955182/find-names-of-top-n-highest-value-columns-in-each-pandas-dataframe-row)

1) **Use Python Decorate-Sort-Undecorate with a `.apply(lambda ...)` on each row to insert the column names, do the np.argsort, keep the top-n, reformat the answer**. (I think this is cleaner).

```
import numpy as np

# Apply Decorate-Sort row-wise to our df, and slice the top-n columns within each row...

sort_decr2_topn = lambda row, nlargest=2:
    sorted(pd.Series(zip(df.columns, row)), key=lambda cv: -cv[1]) [:nlargest]

tmp = df.apply(sort_decr2_topn, axis=1)

0    [(b, 4), (a, 1)]
1    [(b, 6), (c, 4)]
2    [(c, 8), (a, 1)]

# then your result (as a pandas DataFrame) is...
np.array(tmp)
array([[('b', 4), ('a', 1)],
       [('b', 6), ('c', 4)],
       [('c', 8), ('a', 1)]], dtype=object)
# ... or as a list of rows is
tmp.values.tolist()
#... and you can insert the row-indices 0,1,2 with 
zip(tmp.index, tmp.values.tolist())
[(0, [('b', 4), ('a', 1), ('c', 0)]), (1, [('b', 6), ('c', 4), ('a', 2)]), (2, [('c', 8), ('a', 1), ('b', 0)])]
```

2) **Get the matrix of `topnlocs` as follows, then use it both to reindex into df.columns, and df.values, and combine that output**:

```
import numpy as np

nlargest = 2
topnlocs = np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)[:, 0:nlargest]
# ... now you can use topnlocs to reindex both into df.columns, and df.values, then reformat/combine them somehow
# however it's painful trying to apply that NumPy array of indices back to df or df.values,
```

See [How to get away with a multidimensional index in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962113/how-to-get-away-with-a-multidimensional-index-in-pandas)

Comment: So I went the extra five miles and gave you working code. It was quite painful. Option 1) sounds less pandas-thonic, but works better.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, except 1) `ix` is deprecated, 2) changing that line to use `iloc` produces `Too many indexers`. I'm using pandas 0.25.3.

Comment: I'm getting syntax error in sort_decr2_topn  function